Unable to Retrieve Data Using get_program_account with SPL Token Program (Python)
I'm developing a script to track newly created tokens on the Solana network. However, I'm encountering an issue when attempting to retrieve data using client.get_program_account. Despite my efforts, I'm not receiving any data.
Here's a snippet of my code:
from solana.rpc.api import Client, Pubkey
import time

def main():
    endpoint = "https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com"
    client = Client(endpoint)
    
    token_program_pubkey = Pubkey.from_string("TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA")
    
    try:
        response = client.get_program_accounts(token_program_pubkey)

Despite trying alternatives like get_program_accounts_json_parse, the issue persists, with no data returned. Here's another excerpt of my code:
def main():
    endpoint = "https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com"
    solana_client = Client(endpoint)
    token_program_address = Pubkey.from_string("TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA")

    start_time = time.time()
    all_accounts_data = []

    while time.time() - start_time < 60:
        try:
            response = solana_client.get_program_accounts_json_parsed(token_program_address)
            all_accounts_data.extend(response)

Any insights on why the data isn't being read would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Because the SPL Token Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA has so many accounts, most RPC providers prohibit calling get_program_accounts with it. It would return millions of accounts, using up huge amounts of bandwidth and processing power. So you have to use other calls like getTokenAccountsByOwner.
